# Where condition didn't filter the records without complete the word in Laravel conroller

Tags: php, laravel

I want to search the book with the Author's Name. if the author is `F. U. Umesh`  I passed `F. U. Umesh` then it works fine. But, When I Pass without `.` like: `F U Umesh`. No, Result was found. code on Controller like this:

```
$data['books'] = BookMaster::select('id', 'code', 'title', 'image', 'categories', 'author', 'publisher', 'status')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                if ($request->has('author')) {
                    $query->where('author', 'like', '%'.$request->author.'%');
                    $this->filter_query['author'] = $request->author;
                }
            })
            ->orderBy('code','asc')
            ->get();
```

If you have an idea about that Please guide me.
I need to search without `.` like: `F U Umesh`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with these 2 codes

1.

```
$data['books'] = BookMaster::select('id', 'code', 'title', 'image', 'categories', 'author', 'publisher', 'status')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                if ($request->has('author')) {
                    $query->where('author', 'LIKE', str_replace(' ', '%', $request->author));
                    $this->filter_query['author'] = $request->author;
                }
            })
            ->orderBy('code','asc')
            ->get();
```

or use this

```
$data['books'] = BookMaster::select('id', 'code', 'title', 'image', 'categories', 'author', 'publisher', 'status')
                ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                    if ($request->has('author')) {
                        $query->->whereRaw('author REGEXP ?', [str_replace(' ', '\\.? ', $request->author)]);
                        $this->filter_query['author'] = $request->author;
                    }
                })
                ->orderBy('code','asc')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you sir, fine with $query->whereRaw('author REGEXP ?', [str_replace(' ', '\\.? ', $request->author)]);

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behavior. You'd need to add a specific `WHERE` clause to that SQL query. Something like

`WHERE REPLACE(author, ".", "") LIKE %...%`

But if you want to keep both behaviors, adding an `orWhere` could work.

```php
if ($request->has('author')) {
    $query->where('author', 'like', '%'.$request->author.'%')
          ->orWhereRaw('REPLACE(author, ".", "") LIKE %?%', [$request->author]);
          //->orWhere(DB::raw('REPLACE(author, ".", "")', 'like', "%$request->author%");
}
```